# Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe in http post multipart ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multipartform-data, ruby-on-rails-6, net-http

I'm using the below code to upload a multipart image data from ruby on rails code to a http endpoint

```
require 'net/http/post/multipart'

uri=URI.parse("url here")
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: (uri.scheme=='https'), open_timeout: 5, read_timeout: 120) do |http|
  image_file = File.open(params["file"].tempfile)
  data = {"data1":"value1", "data2":"value2" ,"file": UploadIO.new(image_file, "image/jpeg", "image.jpg")}
  upload_sample = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new(uri, data).tap do |req|
                    req["Authorization"] = "Bearer token_here"
                  end
  http.request(upload_sample)
end
```

But i'm getting this error

```
Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe
from .rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:207:in `write
```

What am I missing here?
I'm using rails 6